# Difference in folder size between properties and du -s

Tags: linux, filesystems, rhel-6

I run RHEL 6.6.

When look at my home folder and run `du -sh .` it shows 7.2G whereas when I open it via the `gui` it shows only 6.3GB. I did reboot the machine just to be sure that [no more file handles are open](https://superuser.com/questions/279497/difference-between-df-k-and-du-sh).

Where does this discrepancy come from?

Comment: maybe GUI count 1MB as 1 million of bytes

Comment: I confirm this behavior.  Checking "Show hidden and backup files" checked in preferences brings the totals closer, but there still is a discrepancy.

Answer (score 2):

[`du`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/du) counts sizes based on the *blocks* used in a *filesystem*, since that is where the space is important.  The properties dialog is probably counting the total of file sizes (based on bytes), so that you can estimate how much space is needed on "any" filesystem.

Because blocks hold many bytes, and partially filled blocks count as much as full blocks (for `du`), its totals are usually larger than what you get based on just a byte-count.